# SQL Where Clause with Joined Table - OR works, but AND Doesn't

Tags: sql, t-sql

Assume I have 2 tables defined as follows:

```
Items
-----
Id (Primary Key)
ItemName


ItemsTags
-----
ItemId (Primary Key)
TagName (Primary Key)
```

and filled with the following data:

```
Items
-----
1, Item1
2, Item2
3, Item3

ItemsTags
--------
1, Tag1
1, Tag2
1, Tag3
2, Tag3
3, Tag4
3, Tag5
```

Assuming I want to search of items that have EITHER Tag1 or Tag3 assigned, the following query works:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Items.Id
FROM Items INNER JOIN ItemsTags
    ON Items.Id = ItemsTags.ItemId
WHERE ItemsTags.TagName = 'Tag1' OR ItemsTags.TagName = 'Tag3'
```

resulting in 1 and 3 being returned.

However, how do I modify that query to give me items that have BOTH Tag1 and Tag3?  The following query does not work, obviously, because for any given row, TagName cannot be two different values at once.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Items.Id
FROM Items INNER JOIN ItemsTags
     ON Items.Id = ItemsTags.ItemId
WHERE ItemsTags.TagName = 'Tag1' AND ItemsTags.TagName = 'Tag3'
```

What is the correct query?  In my example, I would want to get only item 1 back.

Comment: Use this `SELECT DISTINCT Items.Id
FROM Items i INNER JOIN ItemsTags it ON i.Id = it.ItemId AND it.tagname = 'tag1' INNER JOIN ItemsTags it2 ON it.Id = it2.ItemId AND it2.tagname = 'tag3'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do the same:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Items.Id FROM Items  
WHERE 
     Items.Id IN (SELECT ItemId FROM ItemsTags WHERE TagName = 'Tag1') AND
     Items.Id IN (SELECT ItemId FROM ItemsTags WHERE TagName = 'Tag3')
```

Comment: Tried this one too, and also works.  For my instance, I like this one better as my current code for generating the SQL command allows for editing the WHERE clause where it doesn't allow changes to the FROM clause.

Comment: How efficient is this when you start having over 100,000 items, each with at least 4 or 5 tags?  The inner select statement creates a list that may contain hundreds of thousands of results.  Does SQL Server handle that well?

Comment: SQL Server is pretty good at optimizing queries. The only sure way is to generate a lot of data, and test a few different approaches. Make sure you have appropriate indexes too.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.Id
FROM Items i
INNER JOIN ItemsTags it1 ON i.Id = it1.ItemId and it1.TagName='Tag1'
INNER JOIN ItemsTags it3 ON i.Id = it3.ItemId and it3.TagName='Tag3'
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3be19/1)'s a SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Use an exists clause:

```
SELECT 
    Items.Id 
FROM 
    Items  
Where 
    Exists (
        Select top 1 1 
        FROM 
            ItemsTags 
        WHERE 
            ItemsTags.ItemId = Items.Id    
            and (ItemsTags.TagName= 'Tag1') 
    )
 AND 
 Exists (
        Select top 1 1 
        FROM 
            ItemsTags 
        WHERE 
            ItemsTags.ItemId = Items.Id    
            and (ItemsTags.TagName= 'Tag3') 
    )
```

Comment: OP wants Items which are attached to *both* Tag1 *and* Tag2; not either/or.

Comment: @Blorgbeard right you are! I updated the response to use exists to only get records with both. Txs

Comment: That's better! Note that you don't need to say `top 1 1`; `select *` works just as efficiently, because SQL Server knows that the `exists` means it doesn't really need to get all the columns of all the rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it this way.

```
SELECT items.ID
FROM items
INNER JOIN ItemsTags ON
  Items.Id = ItemsTags.ItemId
WHERE ItemsTags.TagName IN ('Tag1','Tag3')
GROUP BY
 items.ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way of doing this just to illustrate the myriad possible ways of doing anything in sql, this time, taking a very different approach to the others.

```
SELECT i.Id
FROM Items i
JOIN (
  SELECT ItemId
  FROM ItemsTags
  WHERE TagName IN ('Tag1', 'Tag3')
  GROUP BY ItemId
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t ON t.ItemId = i.Id
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/78001/3/0)